UnicodeEncodeError at / 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 18-37: character maps to <undefined>
I am trying to execute model.predict(image) in django, but I get an error
here i code
import keras.api.models
from keras.api.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.api.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input
import numpy as np

def image_predict(image_data):
    image = image_data
    image = load_img(image, target_size=(224, 224))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = np.array(image)
    image = preprocess_input(image)
    image = np.reshape(image, (1, 224, 224, 3))
    prediction = np.argmax(nermodel.predict(image)[0])
    return prediction

I get an image and transform it into an np array, I don't know if it would cause an error if there were problems getting data through load_img()
I have already downloaded the code and checked how the image changes, and as far as I can be sure, the image is loading correctly
and i use images paths in cycle, it that right?
#example
images = Image.objects.filter(user_id=user)
for image in images:
    image_list.append(image.image.path)
for img in image_list:
    result = image_predict(img)

prediction should be equal to for example 3
the error occurs when running the line model.predict(image)
I've already tried making changes to the encoding, fast API, and changing the dataset.
model is
>>> model
<Sequential name=sequential, built=True>


What you are leaving out is how the image data is being received. Most likely this is not actually loaded image data, and it may be the actual byte stream of an image file, meaning that and you will need to decode it before you start using it. However, what is more suspect is load_img. This indicates to me that what you're expecting is a path to a file, but you do not have the source provided for this function. As is, your question cannot be answered. Please strive to provide a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

i found the answer, this model return progress bar in cmd, that's what django can't encode or decode,
the solution to the problem: model.predict(image, verbose=0)

i found the answer, this model return progress bar in cmd, that's what django can't encode or decode, the solution to the problem:
model.predict(image, verbose=0)

